# Dynkin Hunt formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, dirichlet-forms

I have a question about Dynkin **Hunt** formula.

Last day, I found a formula in this paper [enter link description here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/06bb/40bf01bee9cecaea7aa2e9e7cda7cb5c35e9.pdf).
The formula is the equation (2.5) in this paper, which is called Dynkin **Hunt** formula. I know Dynkin formula. Dynkin formula states
\begin{align*}
R_{\alpha}f(x)=R_{\alpha}^{U}f(x)+E_{x}[e^{-\alpha \tau_{U}}R_{\alpha}f(X_{\tau_{U}})],
\end{align*}
where $\{X_t,P_x\}$ is a Markov(Hunt) process defined on a topological space $E$ and $R_{\alpha}$ is its resolvent. $R_{\alpha}^{U}f(x)$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}
R_{\alpha}^{U}f(x)=E_{x}[\int_{0}^{\tau_{U}}e^{-\alpha t}f(X_t)\,dt],
\end{equation*}
where $\tau_{U}$ is the first exit time from an open set $U$. In other words, $R_{\alpha}^{U}$ is the resolvent of subprocess $(X_{t}^{U},P_x)$ of $(X_t,P_x)$ on $U$.

You can see this formula in *Dirichlet Forms and Symmetric Markov Processes* by M. Fukushima, Y. Oshima, and M. Takeda. The equation (4.1.6) in this book is Dynkin formula.

**Question**

Assume $\{X_t\}$ has transition probability density function $p(t,x,y)$ and transition density function of $\{X_{t}^{U}\}$ is denoted by $p^{U}(t,x,y)$.

Can we show the Dynkin-**Hunt** formula
\begin{equation*}
p(t,x,y)=p^{U}(t,x,y)+E_{x}[1_{\{\tau_{U} \le t\}}p(t-\tau_{U},x,y)]
\end{equation*}
for every $t>0$, $x,y \in E$?

**My attempt**

Assume resolvent density $R_{\alpha}(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$. Then, 
from Dynkin formula, we see
\begin{equation*}
R_{\alpha}(x,y)=R_{\alpha}^{U}(x,y)+E_{x}[e^{-\alpha \tau_{U}}r_{\alpha}(X_{\tau_{Y}},y)]
\end{equation*}
for every $\alpha>0,x,y \in E$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}p(t,x,y)\,dt
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}p^{U}(t,x,y)\,dt \\
&+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}E_{x}[1_{\{\tau_{U} \le t\}}p(t-\tau_{U},X_{\tau_{U}},y)]\,dt
\end{align*}
Therefore, for every $x,y \in E$,
\begin{equation*}
p(t,x,y)=p^{U}(t,x,y)+E_{x}[1_{\{\tau_{U} \le t\}}p(t-\tau_{U},x,y)]
\end{equation*}
holds for a.e. $t$. Can we refine this equation? That is, can we show 
\begin{equation*}
p(t,x,y)=p^{U}(t,x,y)+E_{x}[1_{\{\tau_{U} \le t\}}p(t-\tau_{U},x,y)]
\end{equation*}
for every $t>0$, $x,y \in E$?

**If you know related works about Dynkin-Hunt formula, please let me know.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of the paper you cite mis-state the matter slightly. Dynkin's formula is indeed a direct consequence of the strong Markov property. Your Laplace inversion argument (with no assumption of continuity) shows that for each fixed $x$,
$$
p(t,x,y)=p^{U}(t,x,y)+E_{x}[1_{\{\tau_{U} \le t\}}p(t-\tau_{U},x,y)]
$$
for $m\otimes\lambda$-a.e. $(y,t)$, where $m$ is the symmetry measure of $X$ and $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$. The key observation now is that the two sides of this identity, as functions of $(y,t)$,  are *finely continuous* with respect to the space-time process $(X_t, r-t)_{0\le t<r}$, for which $m\otimes\lambda$ is a  reference measure. As such, the two sides of the identity agree *for all* $(y,t)$. A nice discussion of such methods can be found in the paper "Excursions of dual processes" by R.K. Getoor and M.J. Sharpe [*Advances in Mathematics* **45** (1982) 259–309]. A detailed discussion of the "Dynkin-Hunt" identity, in the context of Brownian motion, appears in the book *From Brownian motion to Schrödinger's equation* of K.L. Chung and Z.X. Zhao. In the paper you cite, the proces $X$ is symmetric, so arguments based on *quasi-continuity* come into play; perhaps this is what the authors had in mind.

Comment: Thank you for telling me the reference! Corollary (3.14) in this paper  may be what I was looking for.