Heat kernel convergence when expanding domains
Let $\Omega$ be an arbitrary domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. There exists a positive $C^{\infty}$ function $G_{\Omega} : \Omega \times \Omega \times (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (Dirichlet heat kernel). In addition, holds the property
$$G_{\Omega_1}(x,y,t) \leq G_{\Omega_2}(x,y,t)$$
whenever $\Omega_1 \subset \Omega_2$ and $x,y \in \Omega_1.$ In particular,  $G_{\Omega}(x,y,t) \leq G_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x,y,t) = (4\pi t)^{n/2} e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}$. We know that $\|G_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\cdot, \cdot, t) \|_1 =1$.
My question is, if due to this monotonicity of the kernel and the bound, we have some kind of convergence, if we take an increasing sequence of domains, for example, if we have a sequence of domains $(\Omega_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ contained in $\Omega$, such that $ \Omega_1 \subset \Omega_2 \subset \cdots \subset \Omega$, we have $\|G_{\Omega_n}(\cdot, \cdot, t) - \chi_{\Omega_n}\cdot G_{\Omega}(\cdot, \cdot, t)\|_{L^1(\Omega)} =0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?
Can anyone who has knowledge on the topic suggest some work for me? Thank you in advance.

If $\Omega_n$ is an increasing sequence of open sets such that $\cup \Omega_n=\Omega$, there is $L^1$ convergence of $G_{\Omega_n}(x,\cdot,t)$ to $G_{\Omega}(x,\cdot,t)$. Indeed, from Hunt's formula, one has the following probabilistic representation
$
G_{\Omega_n}(x,y,t)=G_{\Omega}(x,y,t)-\mathbf{E}_x(G_{\Omega}(B_t,y,t-\tau_{\Omega_n}) \mathbf{1}_{t >\tau_{\Omega_n}})
$
where $\tau_{\Omega_n}=\inf \{t >0 : B_t \notin \Omega_n \}$ and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. This formula gives pointwise convergence and we get $L^1$ convergence using monotone convergence.

Hmm, does the representation of the solution to the heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions by means of a Brownian motion require some boundary regularity?

Open set is enough, no regularity of the boundary is needed. See for instance the discussion https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273907/dynkin-hunt-formula and the references it links to

@FabriceBaudoin Thanks for answering.. What is the name of Hunt's work that talks about this?

@FabriceBaudoin I have a question, and I still haven't found anything clear in the books, $E_x$ is defined through an integral, in this case, the integral is in which variable, $y$ or $t$? I think this term goes to zero when $n \rightarrow \infty$ intuitively, apparently $\tau_{\Omega_n}  \rightarrow \infty$ what does $E_x \rightarrow 0$, but I don't know how to justify this formally.
